# pickerview selectedRowInComponent always returning 0

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

I am using selectedRowInComponent method to get the presently selected row on component with index 0 but it is always returning 0. I have checked it in

```
 NSLog("%d",[pickerview selectedRowInComponent:0]);
```

I have initialized the picker as I am using picker view programmatically. Please Suggest.

Comment: maybe pickerview == nil then selectedRowInComponent will be 0 too

Comment: No Its not nil. When we are printing it in console. It is responding with class name and frame size.

Comment: did you connect variable to outlet? how many pickers are you using?

Comment: I have create it programmatically not in Storyboard. Also It is properly responding on all delegate and datasource methods including - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

Comment: I assume you have placed the NSLog statement in the delegate method pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent: ? Use the pickerView parameter that is passed to you in that method.

Comment: Actually I am trying to place Done and Cancel button on the top of UIPickerview for getting the data of first row without scrolling pickerview. I have written NSLog at IBAction of Done button. So that I can get currently selected row on click Done button.

Comment: I have to ask it : did you try to scroll picker view to other row before you press done? :)

Comment: Yes,I have test with and without scroll, it is always return 0.While I am selecting different rows in picker view.

Comment: is pickerView is a property? maybe you should use self.pickerView?

Comment: can u show the code for `alloc` picker & adding on view, and also method of done action.. and also r u using ARC enabled..?

Comment: You're missing a `@` before `"%d"` (I don't know if this is the source of the problem, but still...)

Comment: could you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you.I am using it in my project its working perfect.

Call this function it ViewDidLoad

```
[self loadFirstPicker];
```

Below is function to make UIpicker which shows only time. (And Save in text feild)

```
-(void)loadFirstPicker
{
    UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    picker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    picker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;

    [picker addTarget:self action:@selector(dueDateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    CGSize pickerSize = [picker sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    picker.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 250, pickerSize.width, 460);
    picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    checkEveryTextFeild.inputView = picker;

    //[self.view addSubview:picker];
    //[picker release];

    // Create done button in UIPickerView
    UIToolbar*  mypickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 220, 56)];
    mypickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [mypickerToolbar sizeToFit];

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

    [mypickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    checkEveryTextFeild.inputAccessoryView = mypickerToolbar;
}
```

This Function getting the time from picker and setting it to textFeild

```
-(void) dueDateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    //[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

    checkEveryTextFeild.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]];
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",currentDate);
    NSLog(@"Picked the date %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try setting both of them. the second line will retrieve the pickerview that the class detects:

```
[filterPicker selectRow:selectedPickerIndex inComponent:0 animated:NO];

[self pickerView:filterPicker didSelectRow:selectedPickerIndex inComponent:0];

self.personInfoPicker.delegate = self;
self.personInfoPicker.dataSource = self;
[self.personInfoPicker reloadAllComponents];
```